# Reading all <p> into array python BS4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Hey I am trying to read all `<p>` tags into an array.

HTML Example:

```
<p>To test web scrapers against invalid markup we suggest scraping this page that contains the following markup mistakes:</p>
<p>It's obvious that not every web publisher pays much attention to validity of his HTML code.</p>
```

This should result in an Array like:

```
scraped = ["To test web scrapers against invalid markup we suggest scraping this page that contains the following markup mistakes:","It's obvious that not every web publisher pays much attention to validity of his HTML code."]
```

My current code is:

```
class Webscraper:

def fullscrape(self, url):
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')
    content = soup.getText()
    print(content)
```

But this does not seem to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do `find_all('p')` and the iterate and store as list.

> content =[item.text for item in soup.find_all('p')]

**Code**:

```
def fullscrape(self, url):
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')
    content =[item.text for item in soup.find_all('p')]
    print(content)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try This:

```
for c in content:
   print(c)
```